# How can I create a sparse matrix from coordinate information?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, collaborative-filtering

First of all, I want to summarize how I arrived at this particular problem. I wanted to create a song recommender using **collaborative filtering** method. But the problem is that I have a very large dataset at hand, **1m rows x 2.2m columns**. If my understanding is correct, I needed to create a **sparse matrix** in order to move forward with my idea, since I do not know of anything that can hold a matrix with the size of 1m x 2.2m.* Hence, sparse matrix.

Now, since this matrix will only contain 1s or 0s in the cells, I've somehow mapped out which cells should have 1 if I were to create a hypothetical monstrous matrix. The information I have looks like this;

| rows | locations |
| --- | --- |
| row1 | [56110, 78999, 1508886, 2090010] |
| row2 | [1123, 976554] |
| ... | ... |
| row1000000 | [334555, 2200100] |

The problem is that I don't know how to create a sparse matrix using this information. I've checked many sources but couldn't find any viable solution. If you could help me, I would very much appreciate it. Also, if you have any notes on collaborative filtering methods that utilize sparse matrices I would also be very grateful.

Comment: You need to "translate" the coordinates into indices.  That is a sparse matrix (e.g. from `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`) requires 3 arrays, row indices, column indices, and values (all 1s)

Comment: How is the information provided to you? As a data frame as indicated above? If yes, one could write a simple script to translate this information into a sparse `scipy` matrix as indicated by hpaulji.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this.  Here is one that creates a [`csr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html), since the data that you show is close to this format.  (That docstring has a terse explanation of the `csr_matrix` attributes `data`, `indices` and `indptr`.)  Whether or not this is the best method (for some definition of "best") depends on the actual "raw" form of your data (among other things).

I assume you can put the data that you show in the `locations` column into a list of lists, called `locations`.  It is important that there is an entry in `locations` for *each* row, even if the list is empty.  I also assume that the values given in `locations` are 0-based indices that correspond to the column of the matrix. Here's an example, for an array that has shape (5, 8).

```
In [23]: locations = [[2, 3], [], [1, 3, 5], [0, 1, 7], [7]]
```

To form `indptr`, we compute the cumulative sum of the lengths of the lists, and prepend a 0:

```
In [28]: lengths = np.array([len(t) for t in locations])

In [29]: lengths
Out[29]: array([2, 0, 3, 3, 1])

In [30]: indptr = np.concatenate(([0], lengths.cumsum()))

In [31]: indptr
Out[31]: array([0, 2, 2, 5, 8, 9])
```

`indices` is just the flattened version of `locations`.  Note that `sum()` in the following is the Python builtin `sum()` function, not `np.sum`.  That function call concatenates all the lists in `locations`.

```
In [32]: indices = sum(locations, start=[])

In [33]: indices
Out[33]: [2, 3, 1, 3, 5, 0, 1, 7, 7]
```

The data for the array is an array of 1s that is the same length as indices:

```
In [38]: data = np.ones_like(indices)
```

We now have all the pieces we need to create a SciPy `csr_matrix`:

```
In [39]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

In [40]: A = csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr))

In [41]: A
Out[41]: 
<5x8 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [42]: A.toarray()
Out[42]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your time to give this detailed answer. I will try to use your solution and let you know in couple of days.